# using exchange powershell - cannot determine the content type of the HTTP response

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a C# console app that I wrote that is trying to enable mail for an AD user.

```
using (Runspace EnableMailboxRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(ConnectionInfo(ExchangeServerURI, ExchangeUser, ExchangePassword)))
{
  EnableMailboxRunspace.Open();

  // Create a pipeline to process the commands
  using (Pipeline EnableMailboxPipeline = EnableMailboxRunspace.CreatePipeline())
```

This works just fine in the dev environment, but I cannot get it to run on any production server.  When the CreatePipeline command is executed I get this error:

> "Connecting to remote server pc799.csnt.princegeorge.ca failed with
> the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the
> request. It cannot determine the content type of the HTTP response
> from the destination computer. The content type is absent or invalid.
> For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help
> topic."

I have tried this running as multiple different users, including domain admins.
This app did work a few months ago, but now it doesn't work.  We moved from a fully on prem system, to a hybrid M365/On prem system and something in that seems to have broke it.

Comment: Did you check that connectivity to the Exchange server from the production server is the same from your development environment?

Comment: Yes everything seems to work the same.  I have checked WinRM connections, and looks well.  I did notice that for the powershell iis folder all authentication methods are disabled, including windows and anonymous.